# Controller, Directive-Controller, Compile, Link - Workflow (Compile function not working)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In following program, the function should go as follows -> Controller, Directive Controller, Compile, Link. However, there seems to be some error in **Compile** function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<people></people>
<script>
//1 module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
//3 controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    //before going to directive 
    $scope.name = "One";
});
//5 directives declaration
app.directive('people',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{name}}</div>',
        //before compilation
        controller: function($scope, $element){
            $scope.name = $scope.name + "Two"; 
        },
        compile: function($scope, $element){
            $scope.name = $scope.name + "Three"; 
        },
        //after compilation
        link: function($scope, el, attr){
            $scope.name = $scope.name + "Four"
        }
    }
});
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Expectation:**

```
OneTwoThreeFour
```

**Result**

```
OneTwo
```

> However, if I remove the **compile function** from directive, I get following result:
>
> ```
>  OneTwoFour
> ```

What is wrong with the compile function that it does not render 'Three' in $scope.name ?

Comment: Hoping this shouldn't be an issue in your code, but spelling error here  `restric: 'E', `

Comment: Nopse, sorry was typo.

Comment: Did the answer below help? Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: I wanted to see 'three' printed by compile function (or by pre or post within it). Still not clear where this compile stands with reference to directive->Controller & Directive->link.

Comment: @Peterson I've created a plnkr below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets taken from the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

The link property is used only if the compile property is not defined. To do something pre and post compilation, return the following in your compile function:

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
    return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
    }
}
```

The $scope variable in not available in the compile function without using either preLink or postLink.

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }
```

- tElement - template element - The element where the directive has been declared. It is safe to do template transformation on the element and child elements only.
- tAttrs - template attributes - Normalized list of attributes declared on this element shared between all directive compile functions.
- transclude - [DEPRECATED!] A transclude linking function: function(scope, cloneLinkingFn)

Here's an example to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/CCnLFJX8D7sbKobuF1GS?p=preview